# How to Create Public Forms in Salesforce to get the Data from Users

Tags: forms, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have created a form in formAssembly and integrated it with salesforce and then use that form in my email template as a button. Email is sent to the customers and customers open the form by clicking on that button and then fill in the fields of the form and submit it.
The data is updated/created in salesforce as Contact/Lead.

Now i want to do the same within salesforce instead of using formAssembly. But i don't know how to achieve this. i tried with dynamic forms but it doesn't work.
Guidance/Help is required if anybody has done it before. I shall be highly grateful.

Comment: Is a part of your salesforce exposed to guest users (no login required to see stuff), like Site or Experience (formerly known as "portal" or "community")? You could have guest users fill in a contact us form, view your product catalog, FAQ... If not - have you heard about web-to-lead?

Comment: No, i didn't expose any page to guest users, i am trying it without changing any security feature.

Comment: will web to lead work for it? i mean how to add web to lead form URL in my email template button?

Comment: web-tol-lead, web-to-case are meant for your own website (pretty marketing, SEO optimised etc) where you want to just quickly dump some form to capture data in SF. If you don't have anything self-hosted, no backend and you want it just hosted on Salesforce - you'd need to look into Sites or Experiences

Comment: Thanks. Web-To-Lead works only for "Leads" & Web-To-Case is works for "Cases", But what if i am interested to use "Contacts" or "Accounts" to capture data?

Comment: Leads can be checked if they're good (qualified) and converted to Account and/or Contact and/or Opportunity. For true support of different objects you'll need to use a Site/Experience or an integration with form hosted on different website

Answer (score 0):

- We can use the web to lead option in the setup menu to automatically add them as salesforce object

Comment: Thanks, finally i have done with it. But its working only with Leads. can we add any other app like "Contacts" in it to capture the data of "Contacts"?

Comment: The custom creation web forms work only for leads and cases in salesforce